# 'Nonce already used' Error using dropbox-js during authentication

Tags: javascript, oauth, dropbox-api

My code is hosted here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/203653/paperless-web/index.html

The dependencies are:

- [dropbox-js](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-js/)
- [jquery](http://jquery.com)
- [sha1.js](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/)
- [oauth.js](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/browse/#svn%2Fcode%2Fjavascript)

In `index.html`, there is no script running the dependencies. `dropbox.js` basically tries to set up the authentication on window load, but it keeps failing.

In WebKit Browsers, I get `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. In **Firefox** I get `400` error, which is documented in [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api) as `Bad input parameter`. But if you plug in the URL for the ajax call in a WebKit browser, you'll get `Request mis-signed: Nonce already used`, which is interesting because I'm using a 20-char length Nonce.

I'm not sure if the problem is arising from `dropbox.js`, `oauth.js`, or what. Any help help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Tri

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a fix to all of your problems but anyway: 
the oauth_signature has a trailing url encoded equals sign(%3d) GQER1BfACC9pdURt04QkWGW3nXs%3D

Answer (score 0):

"""

But if you plug in the URL for the ajax call in a WebKit browser, you'll get Request mis-signed: Nonce already used

"""

That is to be expected as you have already made one request with that nonce, which is the whole point to prevent replay attacks etc.

Regarding the other bits, make sure you have up to date libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is down, but in the future you should consider opening an issue on the dropbox-js GitHub page.

Also, dropbox-js packages everything it needs to do OAuth. You should need your own OAuth or SHA-1 libraries.